# How to get Facebook extra user data from Graph Api using Angular?

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, angularfire

I am following the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/).

My code is like this:

```
async loginWithFacebook() {
    var result = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(new auth.FacebookAuthProvider())

    var user = result.user

    let token = (<any>result).credential.accessToken;

    this.getFacebookData(user.uid, token).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result)
    })
  }

getFacebookData(userId, accessToken) {
    return this.http.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${userId}
    ?fields=birthday,email,hometown
    &access_token=${accessToken}`, { headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': '{data}',
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    })})
  }
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

My Facebook login works well but I want to get the extra data.
I always get the 404 or not found error.
What am I doing wrong?
Am I using the right user id and token generated?
Your help will be much appreciated. Cheers!

Edit 1: Showing error I get.

Comment: Start by removing those line breaks from the URL. And what is `'Authorization': '{data}'` supposed to be? Authorization against the API happens by passing the access_token parameter already.

Comment: @CBroe I have removed the line breaks and Authorization and now getting the 803 error which I have added to my post.

Comment: Sounds like the user id is wrong, that is probably the firebase internal ID? Anyway, you can always use the `/me` alias instead of a specific user id, this will resolve to the user the access token belongs to.

Comment: @CBroe /me worked but Im not getting the extra data I want with  "https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}
    ?fields=birthday,email,hometown
    &access_token={your-user-access-token}".

Comment: Did you ask for all the necessary permissions? And did the user actually grant them?

Comment: @CBroe I am getting data I already have.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: @CBroe You are right, I need permissions then submit the app for review. Post an answer with your comments then I will accept and upvote to reward you for your time. Thanks for the help mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem, the 404 response, is likely due to the line breaks in the API URL, so remove those.

“Some of the aliases you requested do not exist” is due to the fact that `user.uid` is a the firebase-internal user id, not the Facebook user id. You can use the alias `/me` instead of an actual user ID, that will automatically resolve to the user (or page) the token belongs to.

If you are not getting the requested data fields, then you most likely did not add the user for the necessary permissions so far.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. I guess you learn a new thing every day. Never even knew about the permissions lol. Take care mate.